# How to store html in hidden field using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to store string with HTML tags in hidden field using jquery?
I am using the below code. But its not working.

```
var terms = $('#TermsAndCondition').val();
    alert($('#hdnTerms').val(terms));
```

Here TermsAndCondition is TextArea and hdnTerms is hidden field.
In alert it returns the object.

Comment: Please explain exactly what "not working" means.

Comment: It returns the Object, because that's the point of jQuery. It's called **chaining**

Comment: Why you'd want such a thing? Hide the element with `$.hide()` if you want to refer to it later.

Comment: yes  Prinzhorn it returns the object but i want to get the value of text area.

Comment: moonwave99, i want to update the ckeditor's value using mvc3 but on the controller i got the old value which is stored in db. thats why i want to get the value using jquery

Answer (score 1):

use something like this

```
var value=$("input[type=hidden]").val();
alert(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're just querying it wrong, try this

```
var terms = $('#TermsAndCondition').val();
alert($('#hdnTerms').val(terms).val()); //Note the extra .val() so you get the value
```

`.val(terms)` returns a jQuery object, not the value, you need to call `.val()` with no parameters to get a the value returned.

Comment: Excellent!  Dont' forget to mark it as the answer if it solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning to `.val()` does not return the text (it returns a jQuery object), change your test to:

```
$('#hdnTerms').val(terms);
alert($('#hdnTerms').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the value you must call `val()` without parameters.
May I suggest you to simply use:

```
//hide terms when you don't need them
$("#TermsAndCondition").hide();

//show them again when you want
$("#TermsAndCondition").show();
```

not sure what you are trying to achieve there